# How to move to specific ativity after pressing back in android key pad (android)

Tags: android

I want to specify in my code to move to a specific activity after pressing the back button on an android keypad. How can I accomplish this? Friends help me.

Now I found the solution with the help of our friends.

I found the solution to my problem. `onBackPressed()` works after 1.6 version. For previous versions we need use 
`public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`
method

My code for this solved problem is

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.CUR_DEVELOPMENT
            && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // Take care of calling this method on earlier versions of
        // the platform where it doesn't exist.
        onBackPressed();
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

//@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // This will be called either automatically for you on 2.0
    // or later, or by the code above on earlier versions of the
    // platform.
    Intent i=new Intent(AgesWebViewIndex.this,TabCls.class);
    i.putExtra("age", "agepage");
    startActivity(i);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get your point, you may want to capture the "on-Back button clicked" event and then start your desired activity inside that.

@Override
public void onBackPressed() 
{

// do something on back.
return;

}

For more info, please take a look at: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: thank u my frnd i hope this will solve my prob i will try this now

Answer (score 2):

in acitivy A -> startActivity(B);

in activity B -> startActivity(C);

in activity C -> start Activity(D);

in activity D -> go back to B or A other than C

if this is what you want... simply call finish(); after calling startActivity();

---

in activity A -> startActivity(B);

in activity B -> startActivity(C); finish();

in activity C -> startActivity(D); finish();

here if you press back button, you'll go directly back to activity A

hope i'm on the right track :p